# the regular expression pattern does not work in form validation for flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to make validation and I want to check if user's input   contains numbers and letters. So I created this code but somehow it doesn't work. It doesn't reach the first print, but it seems like everything is ok.

my code:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _key,
      child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 2,
                )),
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              print(value);
              print('iam here');
              return 'Plate number is required';

            }
            String pattern = r'[!@#<>?":_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%0-9-]';
            if (!RegExp(pattern,  caseSensitive: false, unicode: true, dotAll: true).hasMatch(value)) return 'invalid form';
            return null;
          }),
```

Comment: Shouldn't your pattern be `String pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'`? One or more letters or digits?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hi, thanks for your answer, yes, it should pass test like this '1AAA111'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to do the validations with regex in this way

```
TextFormField(inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'"))]
```

Comment: This is ok if your pattern is about individual characters.  But if it's about complex things, like space-separated words, it will fail on the first space, because there's no time to add the next word.  That's why validation at the end should be the default, not validation while typing.